# facebook tagging using username from timeline url

Tags: facebook, localization, internationalization

I have mentioned my name in my native language hindi which makes it difficult for my friends who don't know hindi (other nationalities) to tag me. But since my username in timeline url is in english it should be available to tag me, but currently that's not the case.

**eg. if my FB url is facebook.com/panchtatvam then I should be tagged using @panchtatvam**

Since a timeline url is unique and many have used their usernames to personalise it, it is a feature that could allow tagging even if the name is not set in English.

Since this is not a bug but a feature request, I thought it better to get some views on the topic. And if u know any way to request the feature to FB team, do point it out.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Facebook usage

Comment: its a functionality request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always send feedback / comments to Facebook via [Send Feedback](https://www.facebook.com/help/feedback/) page.

Comment: I have already posted it there even though the feedback categories don't match the feature in question. Maybe FB doesn't have any proper feature suggestion option yet.

Comment: I have used this feature without problem for years. Should be fine.

Comment: so the link is reputable then . great :D